# Parsing text from API and converting to object

Tags: javascript

I'm reading data from a text file which looks something like this:

```
#start
#p 09060 20131010
#p 09180 AK
#p 01001 19110212982
#end
#start
#p 09060 20131110
#p 09180 AB
#p 01001 12110212982
#end
```

Parsing it to an object:

```
var result = data.match(/#start[\s\S]+?#end/ig).map(function(v){

    var lines = v.split('\n'),
        ret = {};

    $.each(lines, function(_, v2){
        var split = v2.split(' ');
        if(split[1] && split[2]) 
            ret[split[1]] = split[2];
    });

    return ret;
});
```

This would give me a list of objects which looks something like:

```
[{ 09060: 20131010, 09180: 'AK' }, { 09060: 20131110, 09180: 'AB' }] //etc...
```

However, I've noticed that each entry contains duplicates, which would cause my method to overwrite the properties:

```
#start
#p 09060 20131110
#p 09180 AB
#p 01001 12110212982
#p 20000
#p 20001 ABC
#p 20002 123
#p 29999
#p 20000
#p 20001 CDE
#p 20002 345
#p 29999
#end
```

I would like to hear your ideas how to handle this. My first thought is to identify "chunks" and create lists when they appear, and create a property like:

```
{ 
    09060: 20131010, 
    09180: 'AK',
    20000_29999: [
        { 20001: 'ABC', 20002: 123 }, { 20001: 'CDE', 20002: 456 }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure how do identify the "chunks" in the loop, without specifying the keys (`20000` and `29999` in this case).

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Without knowing what this data is or what you intend to do with it, any solution is potentially good. You need to give a little more detail.

Comment: @MikeW Does it really matter what it is or what I indend to do with it? I've provided the structure of the data, the issue and my desired result.

Comment: You said '_I would like to hear your ideas how to handle this_'. If you've already decided what the approach should be then your question is pointless and it's just a mechanical exercise in coding.

Comment: @MikeW I haven't decided on the approach for my problem - I've only posted what I did so far and suggested a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to hold the values.

```
var result = data.match(/#start[\s\S]+?#end/ig).map(function(v){

    var lines = v.split('\n'),
        ret = {};

    $.each(lines, function(_, v2){
        var split = v2.split(' ');
        if(split[1] && split[2]) {
           // use array to hold values
           ret[split[1]] ||= [];
           ret[split[1]].push(split[2]);
        }      
    });

    return ret;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like it to remain an object, since it's quite a lot of data and it's a lot faster to go by object keys rather than searching each array for the key.

Comment: @Johan `ret` is still an object, I mean such structure: `[{ 09060: [20131010], 09180: ['AK', 'BR'] }, ...] //etc...
`

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Misread it a bit. I guess this would work, as long as I always push items in even if `split[2]` does not exist. Otherwise I wouldn't know which values that belongs to eachother in each array, right? E.g. `ABC` to `123` etc. This would obviously only be a problem if some properties miss their value, which I didn't mention in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how will you use this object, you can use the following structures:

```
[
  {
    "20001": [
      "ABC",
      "CDE"
    ],
    "09060": "20131110"
  },
  {
    "20001": [
      "ABC",
      "CDE"
    ],
    "09060": "20131110"
  }
]
```

OR

```
[
  {
    "20001": {
      "ABC": 1,
      "CDE": 1
    },
    "09060": "20131110"
  },
  {
    "20001": {
      "ABC": 1,
      "CDE": 1
    },
    "09060": "20131110"
  }
]
```

OR

```
[
  [
    [
      "20001",
      "ABC"
    ],
    [
      "20001",
      "CDE"
    ],
    [
      "09060",
      "20131110"
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      "20001",
      "ABC"
    ],
    [
      "20001",
      "CDE"
    ],
    [
      "09060",
      "20131110"
    ]
  ]
]
```